# Find words divided by whitespace

Tags: c, arrays, char, fgets

Is it possible to use `fgets()` to save different words divided by whitespace and then find each word?

For example let's say I have this:

```
char words[100];
fgets(words,100,stdin);
```

and then I have to find each word to use it in the rest of my program. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string in C every white space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space)

Comment: What have you tried?  Looks like you need to loop through the array looking for space char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strtok_r` or you could use the `pcre` library if you want to do things with regex.

```
char *save_ptr;
char *word = strtok_r(words, " \t", save_ptr);
```

and then repeated other calls to

```
word = strtok_r(words, " \t", save_ptr);
```

until `word == NULL`

Answer (score 2):

`fgets()` will save your input into a string. To divide it into individual words, you can either go through the string (possibly using `isalpha()` and similar), or use `strtok()` to get individual words.