# How to convert a string to int and put the result into array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I was trying to convert a string given with only numbers separated by a space into an array of `int`.

```
int make_array(char s1[]){
    // convert string and puts result into array
    char *endp = s1;
    int sum,i;
    int len=strlen(s1);
    int *array=(int*)malloc((len)*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        if(s1[i]!=" ")
            array[i]=strtol(s1, &endp, 10);
        s1=endp;
    return array;
```

The function doesn't work because it gives me a random number.
Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: Have a look to this page on how to split on whitespace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space

Comment: If you give your code invalid data it will go into an infinite loop.  Per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html):  *`strtol()` stores the address of the first invalid character in *endptr.*  So if you hit an invalid character - say `'x'` - `endp` will contain the address of that `'x'` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working version of your approach (with still one problem):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int * make_array(char s1[], int * arraylen){
    // convert string and puts result into array
    char *endp = s1;
    int i, j=0;
    int len=strlen(s1);
    int *array = malloc(len*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
        if(s1[i]!=' ') {
            array[ j++ ]=strtol(s1, &endp, 10);
            s1=endp;
        }
    *arraylen = j;
    return array;
}

int main() {
        int arraylen = 0, i;
        int * array = make_array( "9 8 7 123", & arraylen );
        for ( i = 0; i < arraylen; i ++ )
                printf( "[%i]: %d\n", i, array[i] );
}
```

The main changes:

- set `s1` inside the `if`;
- add a parameter `arraylen` - how else will the caller of `make_array` know the length of the array?
- change the return type to `int *` since we're returning `array`.
- compare the *character* `s1[i]` with the character `' '` (not the string `" "`).
- using a separate index for the output array, since the input index counts the spaces aswell, which would end up as random entries in the output `array` (unless you `memset( array, 0, len*sizeof(int))` first).

It outputs

```
[0]: 9
[1]: 8
[2]: 7
[3]: 123
[4]: 0
[5]: 0
[6]: 0
```

If you only expect single-digit numbers then it should work fine, but `strtol` reads multiple digits if they are available.
If you only want to read digits, you can just:

```
   array[ j++ ] = s1[i] - '0';
```

If the numbers can have more than one digit you would do:

```
for (i=0;i<len;)
    if ( s1[i] == ' ')
        i++;
    else {
        array[ j++ ]=strtol(s1, &endp, 10);
        i += endp - s1;
        s1=endp;
    }
```

to get output

```
[0]: 9
[1]: 8
[2]: 7
[3]: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind taking up an alternate approach, you can

1. Copy the incoming content into a local array.
2. use [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to tokenize each `int` using the space as delimiter.
3. Convert the token to `int` and store into the `int` array.
4. Continue until `strtok()` returns NULL.

That said, `int *array=(int*)malloc((len)*sizeof(int));` is not the correct approach to calculate the number of integers in the string, anyway.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't knew another way to do it, for the part of using strtok, could it be something like this?
[http://pastebin.com/56EsfSRK]

Comment: Codes are very poorly formatted when pasted as a comment. Barely readable. Paste in pastebin or something and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would recommend to retrieve space separated integers :

```
for (int i = 0; i < len && *s1; ++i) {
    array[i] = strtol(s1, &s1, 10);
    s1 += *s1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Note that :

1. the loop terminates when either you have scanned `len-1` elements or reached the end of the string.
2. `s1` the `char *` to your initial text is incremented at each iteration to skip the space separator (or any single char separator). Unless you have reached the null terminator of the string.
3. If a `char` is encountered that is not a number or you have more than 2 spaces between numbers this code will fail.

The way you get the size of `array` doesn't seem correct. You end up allocating a larger array than you want.

```
int len=strlen(s1);
```

If you have `n` single digit numbers space separated numbers, `len` will be `2*n-1`. You may want an extra variable, to store how many numbers you actually found in the string.

I would also to bring your attention to the lack of braces in this part of your code :

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    if(s1[i]!=" ")
        array[i]=strtol(s1, &endp, 10);
    s1=endp;
```

`s1` will not be updated at each iteration, it's actually out of the body of the for loop.