# How to get the second integer using fgets?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm looking to get the second and third integer using fgets

User input: 1 2 3

```
int firstint, secondint;
char buffer[12];
fgets(firstInteger, 12, stdin);


firstint = atoi(buffer);
printf("%d is the first integer", firstint);
```

The output of this is 1.

Is it possible to use fgets and get 2 and 3?

I understand scanf causes issues and would like to use fgets.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I.e. a program that we can copy and build and which demonstrates what you have tried. Also include the *exact* input, preferably as a session with pre-formatted (or code-formatted) text showing the exact input and actual (as well as expected) output.

Comment: I suggest you lookup string formatting in C. There's an abundance of examples on SO alone.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space

Comment: The [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) function might help here.

Comment: If you know that the string has three integers, there's nothing wrong with reading the line with `fgets` first and then using `sscanf` on that line, provided you use the return value for suitable error checking.

Comment: With `scanf` it's much easier to achieve this: `scanf("%d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3)`. What made you think `scanf` causes issues?

Comment: Note that 12 is a tad scant for a buffer to read all 32-bit `int`.  Input may be `"-1234567890\n"`, needing size 13 to read all that in.  Given leading zeros, spaces, etc., suggest 2x or size 26 for one `int` and about 80 for 3 `int`.  No need to be stingy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below extract's numbers from string `str` separated with `,`.

It will work for all non-digit separator's.

Function [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) can fail, it should be checked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str = "1, 2, 3";
    char *p   = str;
    char *q;

    // While we aren't at the end of string.
    while (*p) {
        // Convert string number to long
        long val = strtol(p, &q, 10);
        if (q > p) {
            // We've got number, clamped to LONG_MIN..LONG_MAX
            // You can store them into array here, if you want.
            printf("%ld\n", val);
            p = q;
        } else {
            // Skip character
            p++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
3
```

Your usecase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE  12
#define NUMBER_COUNT 3

int main(void) {
    long numbers[NUMBER_COUNT];
    int index = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)) {
        char *p = buffer;
        char *q;
        while (*p) {
            // Convert string number to long
            long val = strtol(p, &q, 10);
            if (q > p) {
                if (index < NUMBER_COUNT) {
                    numbers[index++] = val;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                p = q;
            } else {
                // Skip character
                p++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            printf("%ld\n", numbers[i]);
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Another possibility is with mentioned `scanf`

```
if (scanf("%d %d %d", &var1, &var2, &var3) != 3) {
    // Failed to read 3 int's
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanations about what the program do, and why you think it's a good solution to the problem posted by the OP.

Comment: This code will not only separate by `,`. It will separate by everthing that is not a digit.

Comment: Yes it will, but in this usecase ive got string with `,`, so i explained it that way.

Comment: Though the example string was "1, 2, 3", it'd be good to mention that the code does no error checking, mainly of `strtol`, and expects at least 3 numbers, or `numbers` array may be left with indeterminate values.

Comment: Hi @FilipKočica and Andre Kampling, just confirming, this will work with whitespace separation as well as  ` , `?

Comment: It does. It works with all non-digit separators. You can try it your self :)

Comment: @Ben Are you with me, or do you still need some explanation ?

Comment: `isdigit(*p)` -> `isdigit((unsigned char)*p)` to avoid potential undefined behavior on negative `char` values if `char` is signed by default.

Comment: You should test if `fgets()` succeeds, otherwise you have potential undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you @chqrlie. I should check answers which iam posting way more. :-)