# Searching an array for a specific character

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to set up a way to search for a specific character within an array. 
An example would be: 
The user enters the string "3456/3". I'd like to be able to search for the forward slash character and assign the values before and after that to two new variables. All the entries will have a forward slash separating the two desired values but the values won't always be the same length.

so, in this case, the new variables would be:

```
int CRN = 3456;
int creditHR = 3;
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space but replace the space character with the slash.

Comment: `char * slash=strchr(input, '/'); n1=strtol(input, NULL, 10); n2=strtol(input+slash+1, NULL, 10);` pay attention to errors.