# C: How to read multiple string fragments and print #of fragments and #of chars

Tags: c, string, algorithm

So I have an **input** of :
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa

(with each group of a being 1 fragment)

and I want an **output** of :
6 fragments read, 55 characters in total

How do I go about this, 
Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think you should define what you mean by *fragments*? If you mean *words*, you should be able to find many examples on the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string in C every white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space)

Comment: What should `"aaa<2 spaces>aaa"` output?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fragments = 0, characters = 0, in_fragment = 0, c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            ++characters;
            if (!in_fragment)
                ++fragments;
        }
        in_fragment = !isspace(c);
    }
    printf("%d fragments read, %d characters in total\n",
           fragments, characters);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In Linux try like so:

```
$ gcc -Wall --pedantic test.c
$ echo "aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa" | ./a.out
6 fragments read, 55 characters in total
```

In windows should be something similar

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing that by counting the no. of spaces and then deducting them from no. of characters:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<ctype.h>
  #define MAX 100
  #define IN 0        //INSIDE A FRAGMENT
  #define OUT 1 //OUTSIDE A FRAGMENT

  int main()
  {
       int i=0;
       char str[]= " aa aaa ";
       int charCount=0;
       int countFragment =0;
       int pos=OUT;

       while (str[i])
       {
            while((str[i]!=' ')&&(str[i]))
            {
                 if(pos!=IN)
                 {
                     pos=IN;
                     ++countFragment;
                 }
                 ++charCount;
                 ++i;
            }
            while (str[i]==' ')
            {
                 if(pos!=OUT)
                     pos=OUT;
                 ++i;
            }
       }

       printf("FRAGMENT: %d\n CHARACTERS: %d",countFragment,charCount);
       return 0;
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 FRAGMENT: 2

 CHARACTERS: 5
```

Comment: Why call strlen if you're just going to traverse the string anyway? Just check for the NUL.

Comment: I think @Roflcopter4 was referring to doing something more like `while (str[i] != '\0')` without calculating the length in advance. Otherwise you're going through the string twice; when the loop is done, `i` is the length of the string.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I totally missed that!!

Comment: @chux Included that!

Comment: @chux Thanks a ton, fixed that! I need to work on a lot of things.

Comment: @chux changed entirely!

Comment: @chux corrected that! :)