# C program to find words containing letter in file

Tags: c

I want to write a program to print all words containing a letter ("D" for example) in a text file.

This is what I came up with, but it does not work.

I get the core dumped error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int findWord(FILE *file , const char *letter);

void main()
{   
    FILE *file; 
    char path[100];

    char letter[1];

    printf("Enter file path: ");
    scanf("%s", path);

    printf("Enter letter to search in file: ");
    scanf("%s", letter);

    file = fopen(path, 'r');

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check you have read/write priveleges.\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    

    findWord(file, letter);
    
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

    
int findWord(FILE *file, const char *letter)
{
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((fgets(str, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) != NULL)
    {
        if (str == letter)
        {
            printf(letter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What were the results of your debugging attempts?

Comment: `%s` is used to read a null-terminated string. `char letter[1]` doesn't have room for the null.

Comment: You can't use `==` to compare strings, you have to use `strcmp()`. But if you're looking for a letter in the string, use `strchr()`.

Comment: You should declare `letter` as `char`, not an array, and use `%c` to read it.

Comment: You're also not breaking the string up into words.

Comment: You need to go back to your instructional materials and learn how to work with strings and characters in C.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513316/split-string-in-c-every-white-space for how to split a string into words.

Comment: What happens if you print the read path before and after attempting to read the letter? What return values do you get from the scanf calls - currently you are ignoring them. Don't and report the values. Read the scanf description, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf You will be surprised how informative those texts are for people who try to use functions and encounter problems.

Comment: TheHawk3r, what should happen when a word with a `D` is longer than `BUFFER_SIZE` (1000) characters - or should we _assume_ that will never happen??

Comment: Thank you everybody for the feedback you are giving me!
I am new to C and i want to learn.
If you have some great learning materials i would really appreciate you sharing with everybody here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mem.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

void findWord(FILE *file , const char *letter);

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    char path[100];

    char letter[2];

    printf("Enter file path: ");
    scanf("%s", path);

    printf("Enter letter to search in file:");
    scanf("%s", letter);


    file = fopen(path, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check you have read/write priveleges.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    findWord(file, letter);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

void findWord(FILE *file, const char *letter)
{
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE];
    do
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s", str);
        if(strchr(str, letter[0]) > 0){
            printf("%s\n", str);
        }
    }while (fgetc(file) != EOF);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!
Really helped me. 
If you have some great learning materials you could share.
I would appreciate them.

Comment: On compilation i get:
 fatal error: mem.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <mem.h>
Is it a library i need to install sepperatly ?
I removed the inclusion and the program still works by  the way

Comment: @TheHawk3r instead of mem.h use string.h

Answer (score 2):

Edited your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int findWord(FILE *file , const char letter);

int main()
{   
    FILE *file; 
    char path[100];
    
    char letter;
//  const char *fpath = "/home/kozmotronik/Belgeler/karalama.txt";
    printf("Enter file path: ");
//  fgets(path, sizeof(path), stdin);
//  printf("Entered file path: %s\n", path);
    
    scanf("%s", path);
    // flushes the standard input
    // (clears the input buffer)
    // If we don't do this we cannot get the letter from the input buffer
    while ((getchar()) != '\n');
    
    printf("Enter letter to search in file: ");
    letter = getchar();
    // Validity check
    if(letter < '0' || letter > 'z') {
        printf("Entered character is not valid\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    file = fopen(path, "r");
    
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check you have read/write priveleges.\n");
        
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    findWord(file, letter);
    
    fclose(file);
    
    return 0;
}

int findWord(FILE *file, const char letter)
{
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE];
    
    while ((fgets(str, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Looking for '%c' in %s\n", letter, str);
        char *c = strchr(str, (int)letter);
        if (c != NULL)
        {
            printf("'%c' found in %s\n", *c, str);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the same directory of the source code, created afile.txt file and entered the file name. Here is the output for the program:

```
Enter file path: afile.txt
Enter letter to search in file: e
Looking for 'e' in This file contains some text.

'e' found in This file contains some text.

Looking for 'e' in This file is used for testing purposes.

'e' found in This file is used for testing purposes.

Looking for 'e' in This file must be read only.

'e' found in This file must be read only.
```

And here is the afile.txt file content:

```
This file contains some text.
This file is used for testing purposes.
This file must be read only.
```

You are encouraged to split a line of string into the words and search the letter in the word list.