# Sorting Names in file in Lexicographic Order

Tags: c

You have a text file eg:`dataBaseSmall.txt` that has names of your N friends and their corresponding mobile numbers in the following format. (A name (without spaces) followed by a space and the corresponding phone number) as follows

```
Kalimohan +917555501305
Bhooshit +918555346394
Ahsan +919055511641
Duranjaya +919155578267
Jahan +919655526742
Bharat +918555026818
```

Your task is to write a program that reads the given file and prints the names in lexicographical order.

Example:

Input: dataBaseSmall.txt

```
6
```

where dataBaseSmall.txt contains details of N = 6 friends.

```
    Kalimohan +917555501305
    Bhooshit +918555346394
    Ahsan +919055511641
    Duranjaya +919155578267
    Jahan +919655526742
    Bharat +918555026818
```

Output:

```
Ahsan
Bharat
Bhooshit
Duranjaya
Jahan
Kalimohan
```

Explanation: The names are printed in lexicographic (dictionary) order.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Friend{
    char name[20];
    char mobile[20];
};
typedef struct Friend Friend;

 //feel free to use string functions such as strlen, strcmp etc.
//create functions and modularize your solution. 
//solving this problem should take you a good amount of time. Have patience and take it as a challenge. 

int main(){
    char filename[100], str[100];
    int N;
    FILE* fp;
    
    Friend* myFriends = (Friend*)malloc(N*sizeof(Friend));
    
    scanf("%s", filename);
    scanf("%d", &N);
    
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    
    fscanf(fp, "%s", *myFriends);
    fprintf
    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be really nice if someone can help me..stuck with it for days.

Comment: If you've been stuck then please explain which part you've been stuck on, and show us what you've tried. If we do your coursework for you how do you learn?

Comment: with the standard C library functions: [`qsort()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/qsort.html) and `strcmp()`.

Comment: You have tried to allocate `N*sizeof(Friend)` bytes of memory even before `N` is actually initialized or read from the `stdin` !

Comment: @DhathriMeda Do you want the sorting algorithm to be implemented or using the library function `qsort()` is fine?

Comment: @DhathriMeda: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, as theoctober19th has pointed out, you are using the value `N` before it is initialized, which means it will have a garbage value in the call to `malloc(N * sizeof(Friend))`. Furthermore, you will not be able to read in the whole file in a single call to `fscanf()`, you will need to use a  while loop to get each line of the file and (likely) store the input in an array. Lastly, you will need to write a function to sort the array of `struct Friend`'s once you have read them in. I have not written this code for you, however, as I get the idea this is an assignment for school.

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle the problem step by step:

1. Read the file
2. Create a `Friend` array
3. Sort the array
4. Print the sorted names

I have started by creating a struct called `FileResult`:

```
#include <studio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define INITIAL_LINE_COUNT 1000

struct FileResult
{
    char **lines; // array of strings, each string is one line
    int linecount; // number of lines
    int succeeded; // read status, 0: unsuccessful
};
typedef struct FileResult FileResult;
```

---

Now, let's read the file. I have created a function called `readfile()`:

```
FileResult readfile(char filename[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[LINE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    FileResult result;

    // Initialize number of lines to 0
    result.linecount = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        //Failed
        result.succeeded = 0;
        return result;
    }
    // Allocate memory for pointers to strings(lines)
    result.lines = malloc(INITIAL_LINE_COUNT * sizeof(char *));
    while (fgets(buffer, LINE_BUFFER_SIZE, fp))
    {
        // Get line length
        int len = strlen(buffer);
        // Allocate memory as large as the line count + 1 for null termination character
        result.lines[result.linecount] = malloc(len * sizeof(char) + 1);
        //Copy read line to lines array
        strcpy(result.lines[result.linecount], buffer);
        //Increment number of lines
        result.linecount++;
    }
    // Shrink unused memory
    result.lines = realloc(result.lines, result.linecount * sizeof(char *));
    fclose(fp);
    result.succeeded = 1;
    return result;
}
```

---

Next, I will create a `createFriends()` function that will parse each line and create a variable of `Friend` and then return a dynamically allocated array. I have used the [`strtok()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4513437/11455105) function to split the string at space:

```
Friend* createfriends(char **lines, int linecount)
{
    // Allocate space for as many friends as there are lines
    Friend *friends = malloc(sizeof(Friend) * linecount);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
    {
        //strtok is used to split the string on the specified delimiters
        // " " and "\n" are used as delimiters
        friends[i].name = strtok(lines[i], " \n");
        friends[i].mobile = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

    return friends;
}
```

---

Next, create a function that tells the sort function how to compare two `Friend` instances:

```
//Compare function to be used for sorting (compares by name)
int friendcompare(const void *f1, const void *f2)
{
    Friend *friend1 = (Friend *)f1;
    Friend *friend2 = (Friend *)f2;
    return strcmp(friend1->name, friend2->name);
}
```

---

Our last function is called `freefileresult()` that deletes the memory allocated for storing the lines of the file. (*Dynamically allocated memory must be freed to prevent memory leaks*) :

```
void freefileresult(FileResult result)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < result.linecount; i++) 
    {
        free(result.lines[i]);
    }
    free(result.lines);
}
```

---

Finally, we have our `main()` function that calls all the above functions and does the job. Replace `filename.txt` with the name of your input file:

```
int main()
{
    char filename[100];
    int i;
    FileResult result;
    Friend *friends;

    //Step 1: Read the file
    result = readfile("filename.txt");

    //Check if read successful
    if (!result.succeeded)
    {
        printf("Could not read file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Step 2: Create a friends array from the file lines
    friends = createfriends(result.lines, result.linecount);
    
    // Step 3: Sort the array using the inbuilt qsort function (quick sort)
    qsort(friends, result.linecount, sizeof(Friend), friendcompare);

    // Step 4: Print sorted names
    for (i = 0; i < result.linecount; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s", friends[i].name);
    }

    // Step 5: Free allocated memory
    free(friends);
    freefileresult(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not allocate `Friends` before reading the file and parse the data directly into this array?

Comment: @chqlie Yes, that would be much faster. Here, I've tried to isolate reading the file and creating `Friend`s as two discrete operations. Also, I can use `FileResult.linecount` to allocate space only for as many `Friend`s as there are lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start, but you should wait until `N` has been read from the user before trying to allocate the array of `Friend` structures:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Friend {
    char name[20];
    char mobile[20];
};
typedef struct Friend Friend;

int main() {
    char filename[100];
    int i, N;
    
    // read the parameters
    if (scanf("%99s", filename) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    // allocate the array
    Friend *myFriends = (Friend *)malloc(N * sizeof(Friend));
    if (myFriends == NULL)
        return 1;
    
    // open the file
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    
    // read the data
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (fscanf("%19s %19s", myFriends[i].name, myFriends[i].mobile) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot read record %d\n", i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    // sort the array
    ...
    // print the names
    ...

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```