# Storing integers in a string to an array of integers

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment for my programming course, and in general, the user has to input a grade type (e.g. Exam, Quiz, Assignment, etc...) and a series of integer numbers. An example of an input would be "Quiz 55 53 60 70" (there can be up to 20 integers). I then have to store this information into a struct.

I'm able to store the grade type and the number of grades into the struct, but I'm having trouble storing the integer numbers into an array. Here's my code:

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct gradeData {
    int a_Nums[20];
    int numValues;
    const char* gradeType[20];
};

int main() {
    
    struct gradeData grades = {};
    char str[50];

    printf("Enter a student's grade type and grades (e.g. Quiz 41 20 90 81):\n");
    fgets(str, 50, stdin);

    // stores into numValues (total number of grades).
    for (int i = 0; i <= str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            grades.numValues ++;
        }
    }

    // stores into gradeType.
    sscanf_s(str, "%s", grades.gradeType, 20);

    // stores into a_Nums.
    char* ptr = str;
     
    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(grades.a_Nums); i++) {
        ptr = strchr(ptr + 1, ' ');
        sscanf_s(ptr + 1, "%d", grades.a_Nums[i]);
    }
}
```

`

I sought help from my professor and he sort of guided me into the right direction for storing the integer values into the array.

When I run my code in Visual Studio and input the string, it says "Debug Assertion Failed!"

Comment: Your arguments for `scanf_s` are wrong: `grades.gradeType` this is an array of pointers, that decays to a pointer to the first pointer. You want to read a string. That requires a pointer to an array of characters. Change your struct member to `char gradeType[20];` Also `grades.a_Nums[i]` is wrong. This is an integer. `scanf_s` requires a pointer to an integer for be provided for format specifier `%d`. You need to pass `&grades.a_Nums[i]`

Comment: You should turn on compiler warnings

Comment: `scanf` (or "`sscanf_s`") is not the ideal tool for this job; I would use [strtol](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strtol.html); easier and provides more details.

Comment: Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4513316/1025391) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7021725/1025391).

Comment: `i <= str[i]` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

*Your Existing Issues*

1. `char str[50];` is far too short. Up to 20 grades as much as 3-digits each (for `100`) with at least one space between the numbers -- that takes a bare minimum of `80` characters (including the nul-terminating character) PLUS storage for type and at least one additional whitespace. **Rule:** never SKIMP on buffer size. Users can and will type more than they should. Minimum of 1K buffers unless on embedded systems is recommended.
2. for `gradeType` you need an array of `char` not an array of *pointers-to* `char`,
3. good job using `fgets()` to read the input,
4. there is no need to loop counting spaces, you can simply increment `numValues` as you perform your conversions to `int`,
5. an empty brace-initializer is fine in C++, but not C. If you had full warnings enabled you would have learned `"warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces"`. (either use a *named-initializer* or provide a initializer/value for each member),
6. to enable warnings, for `gcc` use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` and consider `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors. Since you are attempting to use `sscanf_s` it is likely you are using `cl.exe` the compiler/linker for VS. There enabling `/W3` is sufficient,
7. you can't use any input or conversion function correctly unless you validate the input or conversion succeeded or failed by ***checking the return***,
8. `for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(grades.a_Nums); i++)` invokes *Undefined Behavior* attempting to convert `80` values. `sizeof(grades.a_Nums)` is, e.g. `20 int` times `4-bytes per int` equals `80`. If you do it that way, and presuming your loop counting spaces results in the correct number of values, your loop would be `for (int i = 0; i < grades.numValues; i++)`.

*Comments On Your Approach*

While you can use `sscanf()` if you include the `"%n"` specifier to capture the number of characters consumed with each conversion, and add that value to the offset for your next call, you should really use `strtol()` to work through the string of integers converting to `int`. (that's what it was designed to do).

Further, all `sscanf()` can do it give you a *succeed / fail* diagnostic through the return value, leaving you to handle the accumulated offset for each successive call -- and the likelihood of a mistake along the way.

Compare with the prototype for `strtol()`, e.g.

```c
  long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

Where `nptr` is a pointer to the beginning of the string containing numbers, `endptr` is the address of a pointer that `strtol()` will update for you to point 1-past the last digit converted. Think about that for a minute. On your first conversion, the number at the beginning of the string is converted and `endptr` is updated to 1-past the last digit in that number (already set up for your next call after you assign `nptr = endptr;`) And since the `strtol()` conversion ignores leading whitespace, this makes it extremely easy to step down a string converting all space separated integers one after the other.

Moreover, `strtol()` provides detailed error reporting of exactly what failed where allowing you to recover from minor variations in format.

The `base` parameter allows a conversion for any base between base-2 and base-36 (providing `0` as the base will automatically handle conversions to base-8, base-10 or base-16 depending on whether the number begins with a `0`, no prefix, or `0X` or `0x`, respectively). Also note the return type is `long`, so you need to assign to a `long` and then validate your number is within the range of `int`.

**Minimal Example Using `strtol()`**

Putting the above together, you can write an example with the minimum required validation similar to what follows. Note, there are a large number of additional explanations provided inline in comments within the code, as well as identifying areas where you should provide additional checks or validations.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ARRSZ   20        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define BUFSZ 1024        /* don't skimp on buffer size */

typedef struct {          /* a typedef makes using a struct convenient, you */
    int a_Nums[ARRSZ];    /* don't need to type "struct" before gradeData */
    int numValues;
    char gradeType[ARRSZ];  /* array of 20 chars, not pointers, not const */
} gradeData;


/* simple function to print the contents of a gradeData struct */
void prngradeData (gradeData *g)
{
    if (!g->numValues || !*g->gradeType) {    /* no values or empty-string */
        return;
    }
    
    /* output type and prefix for grades */
    printf ("\ntype   : %s\ngrades :", g->gradeType);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < g->numValues; i++) {  /* output grades */
        printf (" %d", g->a_Nums[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
}


int main (void) {
    
    gradeData grades = { .a_Nums = {0} };     /* {} initializer is C++ */
    size_t nchars = 0;    /* numer of chars in gradeType */
    char str[BUFSZ],
         *p = str;        /* pointer to str */

    /* no conversions, fputs() is fine (see fputs() / fgets()) */
    fputs ("Enter a student's grade type and grades "
           "(e.g. Quiz 41 20 90 81):\n", stdout);
    /* validate EVERY input, handle Ctrl+d (manual EOF) */
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        puts ("(user canceled input)");
        return 0;
    }

    nchars = strcspn (str, " \t\n");  /* number of chars to 1st whitespace */
    /* if no chars or too many or space not found, invalid format */
    if (nchars == 1 || nchars >= ARRSZ || str[nchars] == '\n') {
        fputs ("error: invalid input format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy (grades.gradeType, str, nchars);   /* store int gradeType */
    grades.gradeType[nchars] = 0;             /* nul-terminate string */
     
    p += nchars;    /* move pointer one beyond gradeType */
    
    while (grades.numValues < ARRSZ) {      /* loop while array not full */
        char *endptr = NULL;                /* endptr for strtol */
        long tmp = 0;                       /* temp long for conversion */
        
        errno = 0;                          /* reset errno */
        tmp = strtol (p, &endptr, 0);       /* attempt conversion */
        
        /* validate the conversion - minimum 3-conditions */
        if (p == endptr) {  /* check no digits converted */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: no digits converted: %s", p);
            break;
        }
        else if (errno) {   /* check error/overflow in conversion */
            perror ("strtol-grade");
            break;
        }
        else if (tmp < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < tmp) {  /* validate int */
            fputs ("error: conversion exceeds size of int.\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        
        grades.a_Nums[grades.numValues++] = tmp;    /* assing to array */
        
        p = endptr;       /* update p to 1 past last digit converted */
        
        /* note: can scan forward in string to next +/- or digit,
         * to enhance check for end of string -- that's left to you.
         */
        
        if (!*p || *p == '\n') {  /* check if end of string */
            break;
        }
    }
    /* warn if array full and more grades remain */
    if (grades.numValues == ARRSZ && strpbrk (p, "+-0123456789")) {
        puts ("warning: array full and additional grades remain");
    }
    
    prngradeData (&grades);     /* output results */
}
```

(**note:** on Windows <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> is used to generate a manual `EOF` instead of <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> for Linux)

**Example Use/Output**

Your example:

```
$ ./bin/gradetype
Enter a student's grade type and grades (e.g. Quiz 41 20 90 81):
Quiz 55 53 60 70

type   : Quiz
grades : 55 53 60 70
```

Does it handle all 20 grades if provided?

```
$ ./bin/gradetype
Enter a student's grade type and grades (e.g. Quiz 41 20 90 81):
Daily 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

type   : Daily
grades : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

What if 21 are provided?

```
$ ./bin/gradetype
Enter a student's grade type and grades (e.g. Quiz 41 20 90 81):
Daily 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
warning: array full and additional grades remain

type   : Daily
grades : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

And invalid grades?

```
$ ./bin/gradetype
Enter a student's grade type and grades (e.g. Quiz 41 20 90 81):
Quiz 55 53 bananas 70
error: no digits converted:  bananas 70

type   : Quiz
grades : 55 53
```

There are many more things you can do, such as when faced with a no digits converted error, you can scan forward in the string to find the next (optional `+/-` followed by a) digit. You can then skip over the non-digit characters causing failure, etc... `strtol()` gives you that option with the detailed error reporting it provides.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.